# Insert Array Values into HTML Table

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am trying to insert my array values into html table.

My Table need to have this limits: 5 columns, and the necessary rows, to fit all information.

Something like this:

1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

11 | 22 | 33 | 44 | 55

111 | 222 | 333 | 444 | 555

Any ideas?

---

```
<table>
        <?php
            $i=0;
            $queryPiloto = queryPilot();
            foreach ( $queryPiloto AS $resultadoQueryPiloto ) { ?>

                <?php if ( $i < 5 ) { ?>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $resultadoQueryPiloto['Pilot']; ?>"><?php echo $resultadoQueryPiloto['Pilot'];?></td>
                <?php } 
                else { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $resultadoQueryPiloto['Pilot']; ?>"><?php echo $resultadoQueryPiloto['Pilot'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>

            <?php $i++; } ?>
</table>
```

The data is shown like this:

REFER   Piloto4 Piloto2 Piloto1 O99

O96

O95

O94

O90

O86

O80

O79

O77

O76

---

My Solution:

```
<?php

 $array= array(
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,12,13,14,15
 );
 $verification = 5;

 echo '<table border="1">';
 echo '<tr>';
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++ )
{
    if ( $i == $verification )
        echo '<tr>';

    if ( $i == $verification ) 
        $verification += 5;

    echo '<td>'.$array[$i].'</td>';

    if ( $i == $verification )
        echo '</tr>';
}
echo '<tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: `<table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td>....</tr></table>`. Can't see what is too difficult to do that.

Comment: Show your code. Your array? What you've done so far?

Comment: Try with this website http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables. It generates automatically. But you can learn it. It is not difficult.

Comment: Please take a look at my update.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a static array? Then loop through said array and generate your table. If you don't want to deal with generating the html yourself there are libraries out there that will generate the html for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put the limits:

```
$array= array(
    array(1,2,3,4,5),
    array(11,22,33,44,55),
    array(111,222,333,444,555)
);
echo '<table border="1">';
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++ ){
    echo '<tr>';
    for($j = 0; $j < count($array[$i]); $j++ ){
        echo '<td>'.$array[$i][$j].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

your second question something like this:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,12,13,14,60,3,4,5,56,77,6,456);
$array2 = array();
$array3 = array();

$count=0;
for($n = 0; $n < count($array1); $n++){

    $array2[] = $array1[$n];
    if($count == 4){
        $count = -1;
        array_push($array3,$array2);
        $array2 = array();
    }
    $count++;
}

var_dump($array3);
```

Comment: Tell me something, what you have done it is 1 array with 3 arrays inside. But imagine that you have 1 array with 60 position, not 60 arrays. How would you do this?

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question, with my own code based on yours